# How to transform hexadecimal string into Byte. Java

Tags: java

My problem is that I've to write a code where a MAC direction must be written via keyboard and then, the code must recognize it to mount a "Magic Packet".

Let me show some code so you can understand better my problem and maybe reach some solution.

```
static String realMAC[] = new String [6];
static String mac; //that's the written string

private DatagramPacket buildWOLPacket(InetAddress address,String MAC) {
    String splittedMAC[] = new String[12];

    final int SIZE = 6 + 6 * 16; // See above for this magic number

    byte data[] = new byte[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        data[i] = (byte) 0xff;
    }
   //Method where each character written
   //is stored into a char array (realMAC[])
   for (int i = 0 ; i<12; i++) {
        String replacedMAC = MAC.replace(":", ""); //Here I delete all the : from the MAC adress introduced via keyboard.
        if (i == 12)
            splittedMAC[i] = replacedMAC.substring(i,(i));
        else splittedMAC[i] = replacedMAC.substring(i,(i+1));}
```

And now the piece of code that is giving me problems

```
 //All the (byte) 0x00 and so on are examples of a MAC direction and how to convert it if it is predefined
 data[6 * i + 0] = Byte.parseByte(realMAC[0]);    //(byte) 0x00;

 data[6 * i + 1] = Byte.parseByte(realMAC[1]);   //(byte) 0x1A;

 data[6 * i + 2] = Byte.parseByte(realMAC[2]);   //(byte) 0x09;

 data[6 * i + 3] = Byte.parseByte(realMAC[3]);   //(byte) 0x07;

 data[6 * i + 4] = Byte.parseByte(realMAC[4]);   //(byte) 0x8c;

 data[6 * i + 5] = Byte.parseByte(realMAC[5]);   //(byte) 0xe9;
```

My problem comes when converting the realMAC[] into bytes because of the x and letters from (0x8c, for example) because parseByte only accepts ints and ascii code. How could I tranform that string in hex form into bits?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Byte` also has a [`.parseByte()` method taking a radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte-java.lang.String-int-) as an argument. However that won't account for the initial `0x` so you have to use `substring()`. Do:

```
Byte.parseByte(realMac[0].substring(2), 16)

//etc etc
```

More generally, all "numeric integral" classes (`Integer`, `Short`, `Long`) have such a method.

Comment: What does it mean that radix, the 16?

Comment: Well, it chooses the radix of your numbers; the default is 10, therefore accepted digits range from 0 to 9; if 8 (octal), it will be 0 to 7; and 16, 0 to 9 plus a to f (or A to F). Decoding hexadecimal is therefore done using a radix of 16 ;)

Comment: It is working for me, thank you so much. But i've notices that i must write the "0x", for example  "realMAC[0] = ("0x" + String.valueOf(splittedMAC[0]) + String.valueOf(splittedMAC[1]));" without the 0x handwritten it doesn't work.
And I'm getting an error. 8c is out of range, why?

Comment: Well, I thought it was present in your initial input... If not, just remove the `.substring()`

Comment: Still getting this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"8c" Radix:16" Why is it happening? @fge

Answer (score 0):

[`Byte.decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a `String` that may begin with `0x` or `0X`.  (It may also parse a decimal or octal number depending on what the string looks like.)